# jquery modal popup-locked fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have jquery modal popup that works fine on ie and chrome, but all the input fields are locked in firefox, any input will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

project:mvc/razor
here is code for calling dialog

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("AddBulk", "BulkDialog", "controller", 
    new {disId = disId }, 
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "gcd", OnSuccess = " function() { $('#gcd').dialog({modal:true, dialogClass: 'gDialog', closeOnEscape: false, resizable: false, width:428,height:400});}" })
```

Comment: Model popup or modal popup?

Comment: When you inspect your inputs in FF, are they "Disabled"?  What do you mean locked?

Answer (score 0):

I never liked the @Ajax helper instead i prefer to do code simply jQuery like:

```
<div id="gcd"></div>
    <a id="AddBulkLink">AddBulk</a>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('#AddBulkLink').click(function(){        
         $('#gcd').load("controller/BulkDialog?disId =@disId") //mix of js and razor    
         $( "#gcd").dialog( "open" );
    })

    $('#gcd').dialog({
                 autoOpen: false, // So opens when link clicked
                 modal: true,
                 dialogClass: 'gDialog',
                 closeOnEscape: false,
                 resizable: false,
                 width: 428,
                     height: 400
                 });
    </script>
```

In my opinion this way is much easier and traceable